# VS code mangles command when sending selection to R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

When I open a .R file and highlight a line and press Shift + Enter, VS code sends the line to R, but it mangles the text. For example, if I try to run

```
library(data.table)
```

Here is what I get back from R:

```
> 00~library(data.table)01~
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "00~library(data.table)01"
```

Strangest thing.  VS Code works fine for me for Go, Typescript, Haskell, Python, but it doesn't like R.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the library paths (i.e. the output from `.libPaths()`) seem normal to you?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this @Roger? I am having the same problem when I run any line of code by pressing `Command` + `Enter` in VS Code in the R terminal. If I copy and paste, it runs fine.

Comment: No @Mikey, I gave up and still use Rstudio.  VS Code works well for Python and TypeScript, but I think Rstudio is best for R.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bracketed paste mode is on. Try adding this to your `settings.json`:

```json
"r.bracketedPaste": false
```

Bracketed paste mode should usually be on if using the radian console but off if using the standard R console.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me on VS Code 1.71.2 and R extension 2.5.3.