Run highlighted code R in VS-code gives an error message
I cannot run a chunk of code (a subset of my .r script files) without getting an error message. When I run the whole R file (pressing run source) or row by row, I can run the code without any problems.
The error messages that I get by highlighting a subset of my code are:
Error in `+.gg`:

Error: unexpected ')' in " 

Error: object 'utm_bir' not found
> table(bitable(bitable(bitable(bitable(bitable(bi
+ 
+ bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1:2bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibi = "red") +
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibib1"
> bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibnutm, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "bibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibibnutm,"

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': object 'for_sit_coord' not found


For some reason, I get syntax errors when only a smaller part of my file is sent to the console.
I'm using a macOS 14.5 (23F79)
I reinstalled VScode 3 times and changed my settings, but nothing seems to solve this.
In the .gif I'm first hitting run source, then row-by-row, then highlighting the chunk with the error in the end


What does your settings.json look like? Sometimes R text mangling issues can be solved by setting "r.bracketedPaste": false. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860316/vs-code-mangles-command-when-sending-selection-to-r

thanks @SamR but I already have that in my settings.json file
